# Counting argument in Ribet's paper

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-number-theory

My question concerns a counting argument in the following paper of Ribet where he proves the converse to Herbrand: [https://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/invent_34.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eribet/Articles/invent_34.pdf) .

In the proof of Theorem 3.3, it is mentioned that an elementary argument shows that if the theorem is false, then $t \geq \frac{p-1}{4}$ .

However, should we have the following instead: if the theorem is false, then $t \geq \frac{p-1}{4} -1$ ? For instance, let $p=17$ and $k=14$. Then the set of pairs satisfying (3.2) in the paper are {(2, 12), (4, 10) , (6, 8), (8,6), (10, 4), (12,2)}. Hence $t=3$ suffices to make the theorem false but $t \not \geq \frac{p-1}{4}=4$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I have edited the question to clarify what I mean.  Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think you're right: this problem seems to occur whenever $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$. However, it doesn't affect the proof too much: for small $p$, $h_p^*$ is easy to compute and when $p$ is large enough, $p^2 \le 2^{(p-1)/4}$, so the desired inequality $h_p^* <p^{(p-5)/4}$ still holds.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Surprised that this mistake (although very minor) has not been documented anyywhere. The many expository articles written on Ribet's paper all contain this error as well.